# Google omniauth signout does not delete the session in Rails ('google_oauth2' gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-oauth

I am using google_oauth2 gem to authenticate users using Google.

Sign in and sign out is working fine. However there is one problem.

When user signs out of the application and tries to sign in again using Google, Google maintains the user session and the Google password is not asked again. Is there any way I can destroy the Google session or reduce the timeout to a very low number?

My callback controller looks something like this:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def google_oauth2
      @user = User.find_for_google_oauth2(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

      if @user.persisted?
        flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Google"
        sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
      else
        session["devise.google_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
        redirect_to new_user_registration_url
      end
  end
end
```

To sign out, I am using the following code,

```
  def logout
    sign_out current_user
    session = {}
    redirect_to home_page_path
  end
```

Comment: Hello aadarsh, how did you solve this issue. Its happening in Omniauth Facebook and Twitter gem too.

Comment: Hi there! Unfortunately, I was not able to solve this issue. We can not modify cookies for other websites (browser limitation). One solution is to ask users to clear their cookies if they are getting stuck. 

I was working on an iPad homepage Webapp and clearing browser cookies did not clear cookie in the Webapp container. I got stuck there.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't have a simple/short answer. The important part is that in general, users don't like to get signed out of Google when they are signing out of an RP. 
The more important question is the threat you are trying to protect against by signing the user out of their Google account (please list and we can discuss further). Now more and more people have personal devices and home (shared) devices that are in trusted environment and all these users don't like to get signed out. When is the last time you have signed out of your Google account on an android device?

My suggestion is that "sign out" should clear the cookies for your site and take the user to a page which explains "You have signed out of this site. Login again. Note: In order to completely sign out, please sign out of your Google account" and link Google account to Google home page.